# forecasting with a previously saved tslm model in r

Tags: forecasting

I have a previously saved tslm model when I load this model and use forecast function, it returns this error :

> model <- tslm (y~ x)
>   save(model, filename= "tslm.Rda")
>   model2 <- load("tslm.Rda")
>   forecast(model2, newdata= data)
>   "Error in ets(object, lambda = lambda, allow.multiplicative.trend =  allow.multiplicative.trend,  :
>   y should be a univariate time series"

It seems that the forecast function doesn't know the regression models that has been saved before. Any suggestion how to forecast with a previously saved tslm model?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce, but I think your model2 is not what you expect it to be. I think it is a character vector, since you loaded the "tslm.Rda" into an object model2. I think you should just load the file without assigning it to an object.Use saveRDS and readRDS functions instead of save and load.

Comment: Thanks Miha, the saveRDS, readRDS worked perfectly.